# How to do (Deep) Objects Type Equality

Tags: javascript

Motivation: I just need a poor's man Type(script) checker for externally fetched Json objects against "master" object.
For example my "master" object looks like this:

```
const master = {
        id:"5c60ec7934a4ef6f97da5e73",
        author: "53be2f2e018efa794b42f066",
        author_handle: "test",
        created_at: "2019-08-14T16:59:44-07:00",
        share_count: 114,
        post_like_page: 0,
        like_count: 8,
        catalog: {
          department:"000e8975d97b4e80ef00a955",
          category:"00248975d97b4e80ef00a955",
          features: ["00ea9287d97b4e80ef00a955"]
        },
        inventory: {
          status: "listed",
          size_quantities: [
            {
              size_obj: {
                id: "10",
                display: "One Size",
                display_with_size_set: "OS"
              },
              size_set_tags: ["standard"],
              quantity_available: 1,
              quantity_sold: 0
            }
          ],
        },
        title: "fancy pancy",
        description: "desc",
        brand: "",
        condition: "new",
        pictures: [
          {
            url:""
          }
        ],
}
```

Each property type could be inferred by the prefilled values, 
for example  `master.inventory.size_quantities` is of `Array` type, with Array element being an object of type `Object` with the following inferred property types:

```
size_obj : Object {
id: String,
display: String,
display_with_size_set: String
},
size_set_tags: Array [String],
quantity_available: Number,
quantity_sold: Number
```

Please note, unlike in deep object equality, the "master" object Array, contains a single element against which all element in the corresponding target object's Array should be compared with.
I have whipped up a type checker function, by peeking into Rambda js, below:

```
  const Type = {
    enumed: Object.freeze({
      Null: 'Null',
      Undefined: 'Undefined',
      Boolean: 'Boolean',
      Number: 'Number',
      NaN: 'NaN',
      Date: 'Date',
      NaD: 'NaD',
      String: 'String',
      Array: 'Array',
      Object: 'Object',
      AsyncFunction: 'AsyncFunction',
      Promise: 'Promise',
      Function: 'Function',
      RegExp: 'RegExp',
    }),
    of: function(input){
      const typeOf = Object.prototype.toString
      .call(input)
      .split(" ")[1]
      .slice(0,-1);

    if(typeOf === "Date"){ return isNaN(input) ? this.enumed.NaD : this.enumed.Date; };
    if(typeOf === "Number"){ return isNaN(input) ? this.enumed.NaN : this.enumed.Number; };
    return this.enumed[typeOf];
    },
```

And I could walk recursively through the object and assert if each property is of primitive type and confirms to master, else continue to drill down, but that looks (at first glance) like an inefficient solution, any thoughts how to do it elegantly?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to import additional libraries, you could utilize libraries that already exist for this and are well tested.

For example, https://www.npmjs.com/package/simpl-schema from NPM.

```
new SimpleSchema({
  // ... your schema definition
}).validate(
  // ... your object to check
);
```